# Install4j: how to get user home folder

Tags: installation, install4j

In `Install4j`, how can I get the value of the **user home directory** (like `C:\users\xxx`) in Windows (**the account which installs my application**) ?

I tried `${installer:sys.userHome}`, but it return me:
`C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile` in Windows 7

I also tried ${user.home}, but it returns me the user home directory of the account in which I use `Install4j` to build medias.

Answer (score 4):

`${installer:sys.userHome}` is correct if you use in a text field in the configuration. In a script call

```
String userHome = (String)context.getVariable("sys.userHome");
```

This will yield the user home directory of the user who started the installer, independently of whether the action is running with elevated privileges or not.

If you start your installer as a different user, no home directory may be available.